# How to search foldernames and zip found folders with Visual Basic.NET?

Tags: vb.net

How to search foldernames (for example 'xerity')
and zip found folders (for example 'zerxeritynar', 'hiun xerity natrer' ,etc.) with Visual Basic.NET?

Comment: In code?  Or in part of the IDE?  Be specific with what you're trying to accomplish, please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Basic: How search for a folder and copy the folder in visual basic.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486312/basic-how-search-for-a-folder-and-copy-the-folder-in-visual-basic-net)

Comment: What do you mean in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For zipping, you can use SharpZipLib from [this location](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/). Using this library to perform your request is very easy:

```
Dim sSourcePath As String
Dim sTextToFind As String
Dim sZipFileName As String

sSourcePath = "D:\Temp"
sTextToFind = "test"
sZipFileName = "D:\temp\zippedfiles.zip"

' Zip all of the found files
Dim oArchive As New FastZip

oArchive.RestoreDateTimeOnExtract = True
oArchive.CreateEmptyDirectories = False
' This uses the directory filter (last parameter) to only include the directories that match the string.
oArchive.CreateZip(sZipFileName, sSourcePath, False, "", "*" & sTextToFind & "*")
```

Comment: Thanks. But SharpZipLib gives 20 errors, when used in Visual Basic Express.

Comment: @user1095332: Are you trying to build the sharpziplib library or just use the DLL? I would strongly recommend using the prebuilt DLL in your case.